# Conversion from NSData to NSString is Truncating Where Multi-Byte UTF8 Characters Are Used

Tags: unicode, nsstring, nsdata

In the code below, I am losing the last character in my string.

```
NSString *testString    = @"— choose a category —";
NSData *testData        = [NSData dataWithBytes:[testString UTF8String] length:[testString length]];
NSString *newString     = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:testData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
```

The debugger is showing this:

```
(lldb) po testString
(NSString *) $7 = 0x002ec7f0 — choose a category —
(lldb) po testData
(NSData *) $8 = 0x1003d1c0 <e2809420 63686f6f 73652061 20636174 65676f72 79>
(lldb) po newString
(NSString *) $9 = 0x09109f50 — choose a category
(lldb)
```

The bytes correspond to characters as follows:

```
e2 80 94 | 20 | 63 | 68 | 6f | 6f | 73 | 65 | 20 | 61 | 20 | 63 | 61 | 74 | 65 | 67 | 6f | 72 | 79 |
EM DASH  | sp |  c |  h |  o |  o |  s |  e | sp |  a | sp |  c |  a |  t |  e |  g |  o |  r |  y | sp | EM DASH
```

I am seeing the same problem with longer strings that I am uploading to my server, and it seems to always be where multi-byte UTF8 characters are used.

When I download the logged data from my server, the unicode characters (that haven't been truncated) appear correctly. But the logged string on my server is truncated, indicating that the truncation exists in the NSData object.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. This may help someone else, so I'll leave it up here, rather than deleting the question.

NSData dataWithBytes:length: requires a length value of the resulting array of bytes. This is determined after the NSString has been converted to a null-terminated UTF8 representation.

So the conversion to NSData is handled correctly this way:

```
NSData *testData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[testString UTF8String] length:strlen([testString UTF8String])];
```

To avoid converting the testString twice, this can be done:

```
const char *testStringUTF8 = [testString UTF8String];
NSData *testData = [NSData dataWithBytes:testStringUTF8 length:strlen(testStringUTF8)];
```

The NSString class reference states that the C string returned by the UTF8String method is handled "just as a returned object is released", meaning it is autoreleased. (See the class reference for the exact wording.)